# How to make Eclipse align the ?: ternary operator?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

I need the exact same effect as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841410/how-can-i-make-vim-align-the-ternary-operator-nicely) but in Eclipse.

It should only do the alignment if I explcitly insert a new line before the ":" or if the second operand (the "true" expression) is too long.

Example:

```
a = cond ? "a veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong string"
         : "";
      // ^ put the colon here
```

Comment: Did you browse through all formatting options? Eclipse > Settings and search for formatter.

Comment: I went through all the sections that I think were related and there's no such option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This original answer was for Galileo which is well over a decade ago, so I'm updating it to be a little more current. Original answer remains below.

For Eclipse 2021-12 (under Window though I hope it would be the same across platforms):

1. Go into `Project`, `Properties` on the menu.
2. Under `Java Code Style`, choose `Formatter`.
3. For the current project only, enable `project-specific settings`. For workspace settings, simply click on the `Configure workspace settings`. Then click the `edit` button.
4. In the selection pane, under `Line Wrapping`, `Wrapping settings`, `Other expressions`, there is a `Conditionals` item that you can edit.

The options you want are:

- wrap before operators;
- wrap where necessary;
- no force split; and
- indent on column.

They give this as an example:

[image]

---

---

This is the dated answer for Galileo:

1. Go into `Project`, `Properties`.
2. Under `Java Code Style`, choose `Formatter`.
3. For the current project only, enable `project-specific settings`. For workspace settings, simply click on the `Configure workspace settings`. Then click the `edit` button.
4. On the line-wrapping tab, choose `Expressions`, `Conditionals`.
5. Choose the relevant line wrapping policy and indentation policy.

I have "wrap only when necessary" and "indent on column" which appears to be close to what you want.

If you're not running Galileo, other versions of Eclipse should at least be close to that process. If my settings aren't quite what you want, you may need to fiddle with them a bit, but that `Formatter` section is pretty well the entire exposed interface so, if it can't be done with that, it can't be done (short of writing your own plug-in or finding a more configurable third-party one).

Comment: So this setting is really hard to find... I thought it should be under other sections...

Comment: @billc.cn: yes, the trouble with an infinitely configurable product is that it takes an eternity to learn it :-)

Comment: The trick is that Eclipse calls the `ternary` operator the `conditional` operator.  Thanks for the tip!